# How to access video streaming objects via angularjs approach?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5-video

During HTML5 implementation regarding media capabilities
by referring to https://davidwalsh.name/demo/camera.php,
it points to

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
   // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
       video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
       video.play();
    });
}
```

for video streaming the object.

Instead of that i want to use angular way to achieve this, so i applied these changes :

```
var video = angular.element($("video"));
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.play();
   });
}
```

But from angularjs approach, I am unable to stream the video object,
any suggestions on this or any alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know angular at all, but after [reading the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), I see that the returned value of `angular.element($("video"))`, i.e `video` in your code, is a jQuery object. <sub>(which makes your use quite questionable, or I may be missing what's `$` ...)</sub>

So you need to go until the real element, to set its property and call its `play` method.

By the way, `video.src = URL.createObjectURL(MediaStream)` is being deprecated, one should use `video.srcObject = MediaStream` instead.

So all in all, your code should be

```
// this is an jQuery object
var $video = angular.element($("video")); // not sure what is '$' so I leave it here
// this is your video element
var video = $video[0];
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.play();
  });
}
```

Comment: var $video = angular.element($("video")); actually this should be var $video = angular.element($("#video"));, as this is angular we have syntax like this , anyway it resolves my issue.....thx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The most angular way I've seen is:
`angular.element('#myVideo')[0].srcObject = stream`